# Anybody had success installing a free S/MIME certificate to an Iphone?

Tags: ios, sign, smime

I'm struggling to get S/MIME encryption set up on my Iphone SE. Basically I'm pretty familiar with PKI but all the certs that I could create are simply not recognized by my iphone. Sometime I get so far that I can set the certificate in the settings for my email account but the I get an error when I try to write an email that no digital identity would be existing....
I tried certificates from comodo, startssl, the keychain on my MacBook and some self signed certs created with OpenSSL. All had the same issues. 
What I find interesting is that I can only chosse the cert that I install for signing emails but not for encryption. From a technical standpoint that makes sense (as I need the cert of the recipient for encryption) but I'm wondering why this setting is even there....

I tried so many things that it is very hard to go into more detail here. For the moment I'm just looking for somebody who succesfully generated a S/MIME cert for use under iOS. Best case free but I could also pay a few bucks.

Anybody who could give me a hint?

Thanks 
Norbert

Answer (score 1):

## Instaling

1. First, you need prepare bundle with your certificate and your private key in format PKCS. Generally, file with extension .p12 or .pfx. Typically it require export it from system certificate store depending on your platform.

   - On Mac OS X

   Open Keychain, select category "Keys", locate your key and chose export from a context menu. Be sure you have key and certificate completed (you see the correct certificate bellow).

   - On Windows 10

   Click on start and type "Manage user certificates" and open application. In category "Personal" find your certificate and export it.
2. Send .p12 or .pfx as an attachment to your email address and then open this attachment on your iPhone. You will see a wizard for installing your certificate.
3. Enable S/MIME for your email account in settings. See [Apple knowledge article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202345).

## Signing

Signing is automatic but must be enabled in settings as default. It always uses the certificate which matches email address.

## Encrypting

It depends on how is account configured. It could be much easy if an account is Exchange, but if an account is IMAP the steps are:

- You need to receive signed email first. You can recognize it by verification icon next to sender. Via a click on that icon, you can see the sender certificate and you can install it to iPhone. This time you installs only a certificate along with a public key.
- Now you can write or reply to that sender encrypted message. iPhone will use the certificate until it expires.

More info in [Apple KB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202345).

Comment: That's exactly how I set up my IPhone. The funny thing now: I reset my Iphone completely any when I repeat this setup on a virgin Iphone, it fist works. But if I then import the certificate (i.e. public key) of a specific contact, the whole setup is blown up and I again get the error message as outlined in my original post. I'm really lost :-(

Comment: @Norbert You should import public key by signed message. The first step was about to import your certificate which contain public key and your private key, let's call this pair the identity. See the updated answer how to send encrypted message. If you want to have two identity for the same account, I'm affraid that it is probably not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful creating a certificate in two steps using openssl:

Create the certificate request:

```
    openssl req -new -keyout name.pem -out name-req.pem
```

Then sign it like this:

```
    openssl x509 -req -in name-req.pem -CA cacert.pem -CAkey cakey.pem \
        -CAcreateserial -out name-cert.pem -days 3650 \
        -extfile openssl.cnf -extensions v3_req
```

assuming that you have a certificate authority key and certificate in `cakey.pem` and `cacert.pem`, respectively. I was using the following `openssl.cnf` file with the `v3_req` section referenced by the `-extensions` option:

```
[ v3_req ]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = emailProtection, clientAuth, serverAuth, codeSigning
```

The resulting certificate installed nicely on an iPhone and an iPad for signing and decrypting mails encrypted to that certificate, all assuming that you establish trust for your own certificate authority.